Which is suitable for long distance transmission without attenuation, high frequency or low frequency signals?
I need to understand why modulation is necessary. Why do we need to use high frequency carriers to transmit baseband low frequency signals. I read in some sources that low frequency signals are not suitable for long distance transmission as they are highly attenuated. In other sources I read the opposite, i.e, low frequency signals can travel longer distances compared to high frequency signals. I got confused. What is the correct information? I need a trusted reference.

The primary restriction for using lower frequencies is the size or type of antenna required, and the limited total data capacity available. While we can't go all the way to DC (baseband), lower carrier frequencies assuming the proper antenna is used do propagate further and provide better penetration through absorptive objects such as buildings or foliage. The reason we move to higher frequencies for wireless transmission are with consideration to the antennas that can be realized and for regulatory reasons for spectrum management, where certain services are assigned dedicated frequencies for their respective regional operation.
To see this, start with the free-space path loss formula:
$$\frac{P_r}{P_t} = D_t D_r\bigg(\frac{\lambda}{4\pi d}  \bigg)^2$$
With:
$P_r$: Power received 
$P_t$: Power transmitted 
$D_t$: Directivity of transmitting antenna 
$D_r$: Directivity of transmitting antenna 
$\lambda$: Wavelength 
$d$: propagation distance
$P_r/P_t$ is a ratio of powers, and if we want to get the path loss expressed in dB, that would be given $10\log_{10}(P_r/P_t)$, resulting in a negative dB quantity since the received power would be less than the transmitted power.
This formula applies to the far-field specifically, where $d>>\lambda$.
Note the relationship of power received to wavelength squared! Wavelength in free-space is determined using:
$$\lambda = \frac{c}{f_c}$$
Where $c$ is the speed of light and $f_c$ is the carrier frequency.
As the carrier frequency is lowered, the wavelength increases, and the received power relative to the transmit power increases for given distance (so we can propagate over further distances). However the antennas to realize the $D_t$ and $D_r$ parameters given become very challenging! A typical E-field antenna for achieving propagating characteristics has a geometry on the scale of a quarter wavelength. If we were to use a low frequency carrier such as 10 KHz (for correspondingly very low data rate signals that would then be centered about that carrier frequency), that corresponding wavelength would be 30 km long! For realizing antennas at such low frequencies magnetically sensitive "H-field" loop antennas are used rather than "E-field", which are more useful for near-field operation where the H-field is much stronger, as given by the chart below from this white paper by Hans Gregory Shantz of Q-Track:

Also as we go lower in frequency, propagating waves can penetrate further through absorbing objects and this can be explained through the property of skin depth. Skin depth is a measure of how far an electric field can penetrate into a conducting object (or even go through it), based on the resistance and permeability properties of that object.
$$Skin Depth = \sqrt{\frac{2\rho}{2\pi f \mu_o \mu_k}}$$
Where:
$\rho$: bulk resistivity 
$f$: frequency 
$\mu_o$: permeability constant $4\pi \times 10^{-7}$ 
$\mu_r$: relative permeability 
Note the inverse relationship to frequency.
At low frequency carriers (typically below 30 MHz), the charged ionosphere becomes reflective to those signals resulting in "skywaves" for non-line-of-sight communication over very long distances that bounce repeatably between the earth and the ionosphere. More details on that can be found here.
As we go higher in carrier frequency, there is also the consideration of oxygen absorption that affects certain frequencies when propagating through the atmosphere rather than free space that also needs to be considered. I found this image below showing the absorption at higher carrier frequencies at this link: https://emrabc.ca/?p=17284


but actually, there are many systems that depends on high frequencies and their propagation distance is long, how could they achieve long distance transmission using high frequencies?

@Noha High gain directional antennas. It's all in the path loss formulas ($D_t$, $D_r$. But good luck finding any 60 GHz system that can transmit more than a 1 km! (Given the issue raised in my final plot). This is actually an advantage for those interested in using it for short range high data rate communications as it increases the frequency sharing (reduces interference).

what about mobile communication systems (GSM and higher generations)? I think their propagation distance is long, and they use high frequencies, right? what about satellite systems? their propagation distance is long using higher frequencies, right?

Yes of course, and it's all in the path loss formulas for those systems (mobile systems have even more loss due to fading but most satellite systems are line-of-sight and for that the free space path loss formula does hold up well.)   This is all consistent with my answer: higher frequencies don't propagate as far and so would require either a higher gain antenna or more transmit power (or both) for their use. I'm not saying higher frequencies aren't used, and can't transmit over long distances.

The answer regarding satellite systems is clear. I would be grateful if you could give in a final comment more explanation about how mobile systems can transmit for long distances using high frequencies.

It’s really the same answer… use the path loss formula I provided with realistic antenna gains, transmit power and receiver sensitivity, and you  can compute the expected range in a clear channel. Next with mobile you have to deal with fading channels and there are similar path loss equations that will predict reasonably well the expected range.
